# union of group von neumann

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If we have an increasing chain of group von Neumann algebras such as $L(G_1)\subseteq L(G_2)\subseteq\ldots$ what can we say about the weak closure of their union? Is it a group von Neumann algebra?
Thanks very much.
Roya

Comment: To talk about "closure" you need an environment. Where would the union live? This is key to answer the question.

Comment: Since we work with a chain of group von Neumann algebras, I think  that they are all contained in a $B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$

Comment: Dear Martin, I'm so glad to see your comment. I will appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be usefull to known that 
$$L(\bigoplus_i G_i)=\overline{\bigotimes}_i L(G_i).$$

I would start by looking up the universal properties of the direct sum and tensor products in the case of tracial von Neumann algebras.

Edit: My first suggestion didn't make much sense, Martin Argerami made a very good point. You do know however that each group von Neumann algebra $L(G_i)$ is represented on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_i$. Could you build somehow a larger Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ on which you can represent each $L(G_i)$ naturally? On that spac
e you can talk about the closure of stuff and the question makes sense.

Closely related to these questions is the following paper: 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2799.pdf

The first senctence in remark 2.23 implies the statement I made above, but this paper is much more general. I can't find an easy reference of this property though.

Comment: Dear mathematician42 thank you very much. I actually cant understand what so you mean by $L(\sum G_i)$.

Comment: Would you mind give me a reference that I can find the equality $L(\oplus_i G_i)=\bar{\otimes}_i L(G_i)$. Tank you.

Comment: Dear Mathematician thank you very much.